# BI Publisher- Hide optional page that has a different page orientation

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, xml-publisher

I have a template that all of it's pages except for the last page is portrait. The issue is the last page which is landscape and contains a table with data is an optional page depending on a condition. Currently when the condition isn't met it is outputting the blank page where the aim is if the condition isn't met the page is hidden. 
Is there any method to hide the landscape page if the condition isn't met.
Thanks

Comment: Can you find a way to share the rtf template so we can take a look at what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the entire last page and making it a conditional region.

Comment: Yes that is what I have currently. An if statement that if the condition is met show the data. But when it is not met the data is hidden, the issue is the requirement is that that page must also be hidden/deleted. Current result is when condition isn't met is the data is hidden but the page is still present and is blank.